# I have a dataframe where I want apply for loop for each row and if conditions for multiple columns storing the data in new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe as shown in below image. I would like to run for loop for each row of the dataframe and use condition for each row such that for each ID of column A (e.g 123), if column E value >=44 and column B is less than 55, sort column D for two conditions (column D is time so if above conditions met the duration is 1 minute for particular row) and store the total duration in new data frame. The new dataframe shall include columns A, B, E and total duration.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJu6o.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code, exception or data as an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). It's [hard to read](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/), prevents text-based searching, and lowers the overall presentation value of the post.

Comment: [numpy.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)
is a way to loop through rows, check for conditions and apply something.

Comment: Please add the data to your question so we can copy\paste to test